# Using BlazorBarcodeScanner.ZXing.JS produces Exception

Tags: blazor, zxing, blazor-webassembly

I try to use the BarcodeScanner-Component for my Blazor-App from here:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/BlazorBarcodeScanner.ZXing.JS/

When I start my Application, I always get some Exception. The first is:

```
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
  Unhandled exception rendering component: Could not find 'BlazorBarcodeScanner.listVideoInputDevices' ('BlazorBarcodeScanner' was undefined).
  Error: Could not find 'BlazorBarcodeScanner.listVideoInputDevices' ('BlazorBarcodeScanner' was undefined).
      at https://localhost:44327/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:1287
      at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at e.findFunction (https://localhost:44327/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:1247)
      at b (https://localhost:44327/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:2989)
      at https://localhost:44327/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:3935
      at new Promise (<anonymous>)
      at Object.beginInvokeJSFromDotNet (https://localhost:44327/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:3908)
      at Object.w [as invokeJSFromDotNet] (https://localhost:44327/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:64232)
      at _mono_wasm_invoke_js_blazor (https://localhost:44327/_framework/dotnet.5.0.7.js:1:190800)
      at do_icall (<anonymous>:wasm-function[10596]:0x194e4e)
```

Can someone help me, what can be the reason for this Exception?
I think I miss some setting, but I don't find out which/where.

Comment: Add all the code involved in referencing and using the package. Also mention the .net and package versions.

Comment: Best is a [mre]

Answer (score 2):

(Assuming Blazor Server...)

Add the two following lines to `_host.cshtml` just above the end-body tag:

```html
<script src="_content/BlazorBarcodeScanner.ZXing.JS/zxingjs.index.min.js"></script>
<script src="_content/BlazorBarcodeScanner.ZXing.JS/BlazorBarcodeScanner.js"></script>
```

as per installation step 2 in [Blazor Barcode Scanner Project's Readme](https://github.com/sabitertan/BlazorBarcodeScanner#2-refence-to-js-libraries)